# Deploy ruby on rails on FTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, cron, migration, web-deployment

Is it possible to deploy Ruby on Rails app on FTP?

If possible then how run migration on it?

My app also have a cronjob. How to set it?
How I deploy my webiste on FTP?
If any tutorial etc availble?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it is possible to deploy by FTP, but the question is, why would you want to? It's a nightmare when compared to a modern, automated deployment system. There's also serious security concerns since FTP is not in any way encrypted and is extremely easy to crack into. Using public Wi-Fi exposes you to the risk of your credentials being captured.

The traditional way to deploy a Rails application is with [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) which handles packaging up your application through your version control system and rolling it on to your production system.

If you're not using a version control system that's the first thing you need to fix. Hacking away on files randomly and throwing them to a server over FTP produces quick results but over time it makes it very difficult to get a consistent, tested, reliable build over to your target server.

Remember that Rails is not something that runs automatically like `.php` files can be, you'll need to use something like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) to handle launching your application.

If all this seems a bit convoluted, it's worth trying [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) to get started. They have a very streamlined approach.

Comment: Can you share any tutorials etc from which I take guidens bout Ruby and FTP

Comment: If you want to learn Rails properly, forget about FTP entirely. It's not part of the workflow. Instead look at `rsync`, SSH, and a version control system like [git](https://git-scm.com/). If the only way you can deploy is via FTP that's unfortunate, but I think Capistrano can be coached to deal with that. The reason SSH is imperative is because of things like migrations. You *must* be able to open a shell and run `rake db:migrate` on your target machine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right what you are asking (is it possible to run Ruby program using only FTP as a protocol), the answer is no, it is not possible. Ruby files is not Web static content (HTML, JS, CSS) that is executed in a browser and hence you can just upload it somewhere (as an option using FTP) and then access via Web. In case of Ruby, apart from uploading content you need to execute commands there (start interpreter, rake etc.) and this is not possible to do using plain FTP.

Normally you may want to use SSH channel to the deployment server to run the program after it has been uploaded. In that case upload is possible via FTP, but as well secure version of it, SFTP (or SCP to just copy files between local and remote machines).

Hope it helps.

Comment: But php program runs.Its not static

Comment: Any solution that I run app on FTP?

Comment: In case of constantly running Apache server with php mod yes. But how do you manage its lifecycle (start, stop, update)? Possibly not via FTP. And in the second part you asked, is it possible to run migrations. For that you need to run rake and this is not possible via plain FTP.

Comment: Then how  deploy it? Any simple suggestion?

Comment: You mean with what FTP command you upload? Normally it is STOR. Or what is your question?